# can I use indexedDB within a webworker in Safari 9.1.2?

Tags: javascript, safari

I am using indexedDB from a Webworker, it works fine in ff and chrome, but in safari it throws "indexedDB.open undefined". the weird thing is that typing "indexedDB" in the safari console you can see the object, including the open method (I had not been able to discover how to switch context to debug in the webworker context, something that can be done easily in chrome).

My guess is that indexedDB is not supported within the webworker context, but I can't find doc that confirms that suspicion. I only found that in version 10 (yet not available) "[Safari’s IndexedDB implementation now fully supports the recommended standard](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html).".